# Sharepoint doesn't always execute script

Tags: web-part, javascript

So i have a webpart where some very smart people have hardcoded the number of items to show... So i've insert some javascript in a script editor to show more items (since those smart people just add "style= display: none" on the items 3 and above... ). But my problem is that the script isn't executed everytime, sometimes i have to refresh the page to make it work. And i wait for the document to be fully loaded before doing my stuff... here's what my code looks like:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){

    $(".Merck_OrgLocUpcomingEvents_wrapper").each(function(){
        $(this).find("li").each(function(){
           $(this).attr("style", " ");});
     });
});
</script>
```

So this works but not everytime. I don't know why, isn't it because of cache? How can i fix it and make it work everytime i load the page? I can't edit the webpar's code.

Comment: try using document.ready instead of window.load. Specify type="javascript".

Comment: @NiranjanKulkarni Hi Niran. I did try it but it doesn't change a lot. The execution of the script is still random with document.ready

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myfunction, "sp.js");
});

Comment: can you please place your scripteditor webpart after the main webpart and try.?

Answer (score 0):

try using following code for sharepoint 2013,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', functionName);
});
```

and for sharepoint 2010,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(functionName, "sp.js");
});
```

What is that Id ".Merck_OrgLocUpcomingEvents_wrapper" about??

Comment: The app itself adds some class's names. I will try your way thank you.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. I execute the code in a script editor. Is it the problem?

Comment: Try executing the same code in content editor webpart.

Comment: Try using, $('this').css('display','block');